# Creating pairs and specifying a name for them

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as

```
list={-3/4, -3/4, 3/4, 3/4, -1/4, -1/4, -1/4, -1/4, -1/4, -1/4,
        1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}
```

I want to create pairs with an added selected number in `Range[3]` in this method:

1-deleting same elements,
2-sorting by last,
 3-adding and creating pairs and
4-specifying a name to the list

I use of `Sort@Partition[list, 1]` and after that use of `Appendto` but it doesn't work correctly, also the specifying a name for created data is more difficult!)

```
data1={{1,-3/4},{1, -1/4},{1, 1/4},{1,3/4}}
data2={{2,-3/4},{2, -1/4},{2, 1/4},{2,3/4}}
data3={{3,-3/4},{3, -1/4},{3, 1/4},{3,3/4}}
```

Comment: Using `data[ i ]` is easier and more natural. Why do you want `datai`?

Comment: yes you are right, I can use of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
o = Outer[List, Range@3, Union@list];
data[i_] := o[[i]]

data /@ Range@3

(*
{{{1, -(3/4)}, {1, -(1/4)}, {1, 1/4}, {1, 3/4}},
 {{2, -(3/4)}, {2, -(1/4)}, {2, 1/4}, {2, 3/4}}, 
 {{3, -(3/4)}, {3, -(1/4)}, {3, 1/4}, {3, 3/4}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just define data:

```
data[n_] := Thread[{n, Union@list}]
```

You could also use `Tuples` for a belisarius variant:

```
tup=GatherBy[Tuples[{Range@3, Union@list}], First];
dat[j_]:=tup[[j]]
```

but `Outer` seems neater for the original post.

Comment: Please try `list = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 1000000];
data[n_] := Thread[{n, Union@list}];
data[1]; // Timing`

Comment: @belisarius thank you for the instructive comment. I did not know what the size of the problem this was going to be applied to. In retrospect, I should have more thoughtful and less tempted by terse looking. Always learning...:)

Comment: He! Yours was my first try! :)